# jsonb column in rails table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I have a column in rails

```rb
t.jsonb "supported_currencies", default: [], null: false
```

I have to store data in column like that in loop

```rb
[ { "currency": "USD", "rate": 1.3 },{ "currency": "ZAR", "rate": 1.03 },
{ "currency": "ZAD", "rate": 1.93 } ]
```

or

```rb
[ { "currency": "USD", "rate": 1.3 },{ "currency": "ZAR", "rate": 1.03 } ]
```

from form it can select multiple currency and rate.

How I save data init like that to create table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need to store some arrays in the database

For this purpose you can use such column

```rb
t.text :supported_currencies, array: true, default: [], null: false
```

Just as examle that you can use it as usual array:

```rb
record.supported_currencies << { currency: "USD", rate: 1.3 }
record.supported_currencies << { currency: "ZAR", rate: 1.03 }
record.save
```

Comment: How I take data like this from form <%= f.input :supported_currencies %>

Comment: can you give example for multiple input for this { currency: "USD", rate: 1.3 } { currency: "ZAR", rate: 1.03 }

Comment: It's better to create new question for that